# How can $R_HL$ differ from $RL$?

Tags: complexity-classes, probabilistic-algorithms

https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:R

> RL: Randomized Logarithmic-Space Has the same relation to L as RP does
> to P. The randomized machine must halt with probability 1 on any
> input. It must also run in polynomial time (since otherwise we would
> just get NL).
>
> Contains R<sub>H</sub>L.

While requiring runtime in polynomial time avoids trivial RL=NL, it also allows running time stored. If an algorithm would on average take $f(n)$ steps, then trying to run $100f(n)$ steps would only have 1% chance of not halting, and rejecting in this case doesn't harm.

So why only "Contains R<sub>H</sub>L" shown?

---

Answering D.W.

> What does "allows running time stored" mean?

Logarithmic-Space allows storing polynomial-size integer

> What do you mean by "rejecting doesn't harm"?

If X is in RL, then there's an algorithm that accept for 51% chance for input in X, and we can construct one that accept for 50% chance and never fall into infinite loop

> Why do you think the two classes should be equal?  Their definitions are different.

> R<sub>H</sub>L: Randomized Halting Logarithmic-Space
>
> Has the same relation to L as RP does to P. The randomized machine must halt for every input and every setting of the random tape.

Comment: What does "allows running time stored" mean?  What do you mean by "rejecting doesn't harm"?  Why do you think the two classes should be equal?  Their definitions are different.

Comment: @D.W. Logarithmic-Space allows storing polynomial-size integer. If X is in RL, then there's an algorithm that accept for 51% chance for input in X, and we can construct one that accept for 50% chance and never fall into infinite loop